# In Visual Studio 2017, how/where to configure Solutions and Folders view, of Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working in VS 2017 in an existing solution (i'm new at the job) where Solution Explorer always start showing the new Folders view instead of its classical Solution/Projects view.

I want to switch back to the old mode and let it by default, but cannot find an option to set that view mode. Where (UI or config file) is that configured?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the view by clicking on the *Solutions and Folders* icon within the Solution Explorer

[image]

Comment: The idea is not to do that and get the classic old solution+projects mode as default. Thanks for the try.

Comment: @NéstorSánchezA: Okay, then I miss read your question. This will not help you, but the _old_ view is my default view. When I switch the views it always changed back to the old one.

Comment: You're lucky, my default view is the Folders one (which not autocompiles nor shows errors. So, I feel it less useful)

Comment: @NéstorSánchezA. Can you take a look at you _*.sln_ file. May be there are some variable/properties set like `HideSolutionNode = FALSE`. Or maybe it depends on the project type.

Comment: No relevant properties found in the .sln file either.